# ¿Cómo explico a un hablante no nato, si a cierto verbo le corresponde un objeto directo o uno indirecto?

Tags: objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

Ocasionalmente platico con gente que aprende español, la cual pregunta cómo hacer para averigüar si el objeto asociado a cierto verbo es directo o indirecto.

Yo sé la respuesta porque, ante la duda (lo cual rara vez pasa), uno contesta unas preguntas

- ¿Qué es lo que ...?  → Objeto directo
- ¿A quién, para quién, ...? → Objeto indirecto

Pero las respuestas a dichas preguntas sólo las sabe un hablante nato del español y no ayudarían realmente a alguien que lo aprende (pues, claro, dichas respuestas asumen que uno ya desarrolló su intuición lingüística)

En busca de un método que para todos pueda ser útil, lo que ahora digo es "busca en el diccionario, y si el verbo es transitivo, éste acepta (necesita) un objeto directo".

- ¿Hay otro método, uno más fácil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que tener cuidado con las preguntas "a quién, para quién" y ciertos verbos.

En el caso:

> Me gusta el chocolate

Puede uno preguntar : ¿A quién le gusta el chocolate? --> A mí -> Me complemento indirecto.

Pero si se pregunta ¿Qué me gusta? --> El chocolate --> Chocolate: complemento directo, estaríamos cometiendo un error, ya que chocolate es el sujeto.

Simplemente, cuidado con este método. Sustituir por pronombres o convertir la oración en pasiva son métodos más seguros para encontrar el complemento directo/indirecto

EDIT: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que pides un método.

Convertir la oración en pasiva SIEMPRE te proporciona el complemento directo, ya que este se convierte en el sujeto en la oración en forma pasiva.

> Yo traigo un libro -> Un libro es traído por mí

Answer (score 1):

Depende del idioma que es la gente con la que platicas y que aprende español, de esa manera puedes encontrar un símil en su lengua nativa.

Otras veces es que simplemente se acostumbren al idioma practicándolo, escuchándolo y leyendo.

Answer (score 1):

Una posibilidad es la de usar el mismo verbo en forma transitiva e intransitiva. Por ejemplo, con el verbo "llevar" puedes construir estas dos frases, donde "Rosa" en cada caso es objeto directo o indirecto:

-Lleva a Rosa este libro.

-Lleva a Rosa a la estación.

Si la gente con la que hablas es de habla inglesa o conoce el inglés, una de las gracias de este ejemplo es que se podría traducir como:

-Take Rosa this book.

-Take Rosa to the station.

Creo que el primer paso tiene que ser entender cómo en estas dos frases, la acción del verbo recae directamente sobre "Rosa" en el segundo caso (ergo "Rosa" es objeto directo), y cómo en el primero, a pesar de la similitud de la frase, la acción de "llevar" no recae directamente sobre "Rosa" (ergo objeto indirecto).

Otro ejemplo similar:

-Busca a Pedro en el hotel.

-Busca a Pedro un hotel.

El aprendiz debería comprender que en cada caso "Pedro" tiene una función muy distinta. En la primera la acción recae sobre "Pedro" (o dicho de otro modo, Pedro es el buscado), y en el segundo recae sobre el hotel (lo que buscamos es un hotel).

Espero que sea de utilidad.